# Why the field separator character must be only one byte?

Tags: text, r, delimiter

```
data <- read.delim("C:\\test.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "$$$$$")
Error in scan(file, what = "", sep = sep, quote = quote, nlines = 1, quiet = TRUE,  : 
  invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte
```

Why there is a restriction like this? Can I overcome it?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a potential solution.

Assuming this is what the lines in your file look like

`1$$$$$2$$$$$3$$$$$4`

The following will create a matrix with the variables stored as characters.

```
do.call(rbind,strsplit(readLines('test.txt'),'$$$$$',fixed=T))
```

Comment: if you would the end result to be a data frame you can convert the character matrix using `type.convert`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129926/convert-character-matrix-from-readlines-into-equivalent-data-frame-using-read-ta?noredirect=1#comment61800058_37129926