# Convert character matrix from readLines into equivalent data.frame using read.table

Tags: r

I have a problem using the solution to this question:

[Why the field separator character must be only one byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732397/why-the-field-separator-character-must-be-only-one-byte)

I have a file with columns delimited with `~~~`, and of course `read.table` fails with the error `invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte`. I googled and found the above question, which successfully reads the file into a character matrix.

However, I would like to now convert this character matrix into a data frame, assigning the type to each column automatically, with rules determined as if `read.table` had worked on the original file, e.g. dates and strings get converted to factors, etc.

Comment: You could use `readLines()` and then split each line using `strsplit()` on the `~~~` delimeter.  But this would not necessarily format the data as you want it.

Comment: this is exactly how the other solution works, but it creates a character matrix which I am now struggling to convert.

Comment: Just `as.data.frame` it, and then cast the columns as you want.

Comment: I would like to cast the columns automatically, per the rules used in `read.table`

Comment: Well if no such package exists, then maybe you could create one :-)

Comment: why not write out the matrix as a "txt" document with single byte separator, and then read in again with `read.table`?

Comment: that would be inefficient if the file in question is big.

Answer (score 1):

`read.table` has a helper function `utils::type.conversion`, whose helpfile states:

> This is principally a helper function for read.table. Given a character vector, it attempts to convert it to logical, integer, numeric or complex, and failing that converts it to factor unless as.is = TRUE. The first type that can accept all the non-missing values is chosen.

The bit in `read.table` that calls this function is:

```
  for (i in (1L:cols)[do]) {
    data[[i]] <- if (is.na(colClasses[i])) 
      type.convert(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec, 
                   numerals = numerals, na.strings = character(0L))
  ...
  }
```

where the ellipsis deals with column types configured in the call to `read.table`.

For my purposes the following is sufficient:

```
df2 <- do.call(rbind,strsplit(readLines('test.txt'),'~~~',fixed=T))

df2_processed <-
  setNames(
    as.data.frame(lapply(1:ncol(df2), function(i) {
      type.convert(df2[,i])}), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
  paste0('v', 1:ncol(df2)))
```

where `test.txt` is the following text file:

```
2015-03-22~~~153.234~~~hello~~~5~~~6
2015-03-22~~~153.234~~~hello~~~5~~~6
2015-03-22~~~153.234~~~hello~~~5~~~6
2015-03-22~~~153.234~~~hello~~~5~~~6
2015-03-22~~~153.234~~~hello~~~5~~~6
```